# bind record types to picklist

Tags: picklist

I have 2 record types in contact. I want to bind the record types to an custom picklist and display in visual force page.
I have come up with a piece of code but I am stuck.
Kindly help me out.

```
public with sharing class recordtypepicklist {
    public list<SelectOption> getRecordTypes() {
        list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();

        for(RecordType sRecordType:[select ID,Name from RecordType where 
            SObjectType='Contact']) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(sRecordType.ID,sRecordType.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }  
}
```

I am getting an error in statement inside the for loop.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="recordtypepicklist">     
  <apex:form> 
    <apex:selectList id="recordtypes" value="{!selectedrecordtype}" size="1" title="Recordtypes"> 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordTypes}"></apex:selectOptions> 
    </apex:selectList> 
  </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Thiscode looks working. Please add you vf page.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the error text and *relevant* markup from your page.

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Contact"
           extensions="recordtypepicklist">
 <apex:form>
 
         <apex:selectList id="recordtypes" 
                          value="{!selectedrecordtype}" 
                          size="1" 
                          title="Recordtypes">

         <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordTypes}"></apex:selectOptions>

</apex:selectList>
</apex:form>    
</apex:page>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the `Lazy Load` [pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_performance.htm) here:

```
public List<SelectOption> recordTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (recordTypes == null)
        {
            recordTypes = new List<SelectOption>();
            for (RecordType recordType : [
                SELECT Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Contact'
            ]) recordTypes.add(new SelectOption(recordType.Id, recordType.Name));
        }
        return recordTypes;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Then your markup should look like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:selectList value="{!Contact.RecordTypeId}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!recordTypes}" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I am getting an error as "Variable does not exist: ID at line 16 column 46". I when I bind recordType.ID its where it throws error.

Comment: @KrishnaCasukhela Um. Which line is 16 for you? Please edit your Original Post if you wish to add more context.

Comment: Line 16 is      recordTypes.add(new SelectOption(recordType.ID, recordType.Name));

Comment: @KrishnaCasukhela Did you change the variable name from `sRecordType` to `recordType` within the loop, but not in your `for` loop declaration?

Comment: No I haven't and also I do not have any custom object named RecordType

Comment: It's standard... and this code compiles for me.

Comment: Hi, I checked the code in another user account and it works , but picklist remains empty when vf page is displayed.

Comment: @KrishnaCasukhela try to make the class `without sharing`? If that works you can make just an inner class to mark with that setting.